# how to rebuild a system.img for Android 4.0.4 without odex files in /system/framework?

Tags: android

Following the standard steps listed in http://source.android.com/source/building.html, I can build Android 4.0.4 emulator. And the emulator can be started OK.

But in `/system/framework/`, there are files which are odexed.
For example, a framework.jar has a corresponding framework.odex.

Then I tried `"make WITH_DEXPREOPT=false DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true"`, but in vain.

What are additional steps to rebuild a system.img with only *`.jar` files in `/system/framework/`?

Comment: Pure AOSP or a custom rom?

Comment: I download sources following instructions listed in http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.     So it should be AOSP.